# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_sysconfigdata_m_darwin_darwin'

Tags: python, python-3.x, cx-freeze

I'm working on a Rally reporting tool for my team in Python, and I'm trying to package it using cx-freeze. I'm getting a ModuleNotFound error, and I'm wondering if it's because pygal isn't supported by cx-freeze (really hoping this isn't the case because I'd have to rewrite a lot of things)

```
celinaperalta$ /Users/celinaperalta/Documents/NYLTesting/rally-exports/build/exe.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/RallyGUI ; exit;
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cx_Freeze/initscripts/__startup__.py", line 40, in run
    module.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cx_Freeze/initscripts/Console.py", line 37, in run
    exec(code, {'__name__': '__main__'})
  File "RallyGUI.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "/Users/celinaperalta/Documents/NYLTesting/rally-exports/build/exe.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/RallyReportTool.py", line 7, in <module>
    import pygal
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pygal/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    import pkg_resources
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 959, in <module>
    class Environment:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 963, in Environment
    self, search_path=None, platform=get_supported_platform(),
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 190, in get_supported_platform
    plat = get_build_platform()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 395, in get_build_platform
    plat = get_platform()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/sysconfig.py", line 675, in get_platform
    get_config_vars(),
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/sysconfig.py", line 551, in get_config_vars
    _init_posix(_CONFIG_VARS)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/sysconfig.py", line 422, in _init_posix
    _temp = __import__(name, globals(), locals(), ['build_time_vars'], 0)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_sysconfigdata_m_darwin_darwin'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cx_freeze does not include all the packages automatically. When you find ModuleNotFoundError, you need to inlcude the module explicitly in your setup like -

build_exe_options = {'packages': ['_sysconfigdata_m_darwin_darwin']}